# Is is possible to redirect a page to another url when i click on to the close tab or close a browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to redirect a page to another url when a user tries to close a browser window.

Can it be possible to redirect without showing any message or popup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using SO for propagating scam? Has the chicken come home to roost!

Comment: What's the reasoning for doing this? It's a horrible and unreliable approach. In most cases rethinking your page/app flow a little will eliminate any need for a redirect on close. Essentially the user wants to close the window and you're trying to redirect them to another page. You'd effectively almost doing almost the opposite of what the user wants by either forcing a redirect or opening a new window..

Comment: Lol. I have another code of that page and thats what i want. if you have any idea then do share it. Else Thank You

Answer (score 3):

It is very much possible by handling "onbeforeclose" and/or "onclose" JavaScript events, but it's not a good practice as the end user does not like to be redirected to a new page upon closing the browser window.

If you want to implement it, you will just have to handle these events and inside the event handler, run the custom code...

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
if(confirm('close?')){
    window.open('http://www.msn.com','_self');
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        window.open("http://www.google.com","GoogleWindow");
        return "Do you want to go to google?";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work... As i want to redirect the page to google.com when close button is pressed

Comment: Check my edit. I just confirmed and it works on chrome, however by defaults chrome disables the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [wanjarisushil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6638659/wanjarisushil), this is not a good method.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        window.open("http://www.google.com","newwindow");
}
```

Comment: @Mario Can you double confirm that you've not disabled JavaScript in your browser?

Comment: I haven't disabled that. Other scripts are working fine for me

Comment: Hmmm. Ok, do one thing, try running the above code in your browser console and then close that tab.

Comment: It's working fine now. but is it possible to open google.com in the same tab that i am going to close?

Comment: Nope. You cannot navigate to another URL on the same tab once you triggered `onbeforeunload`. Nobody can stop it from closing. There are few things to note that you cannot perform during the event. Fortunately, you can navigate to another URL on another tab during the event.